# How to color the entire web page

Tags: html, css

I am using simple HTML and CSS my background color is only filling a third of the page and I want it to fill the entkire page. I have tried using the html and body class for background color and this did not work. Here is my code below:

```css
 <style>

html {
  min-height: 100%;
}
    h1 {
    font-size:1.7rem;
    font: weight 300;
    color:#b10f1a;
    text-align: center;
  }  
    
    li {
      float: center;
    }
    
    li a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li a:hover {
      background-color: #111;
    }
    .user {
      color: #b10f1a;
      text-align: left;
    }
    hr {
      color: #b10f1a;
    }
    </style>
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
   
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

 <body bgcolor="#DBD7D6">
 

  <h1>Web Page Blocked</h1>

  <p>Access to the web page you were trying to visit has been blocked in accordance with company policy. 
    <br>
    <br>Please contact The Support Desk if you believe this is in error.
    </p>
    
    <p style="color: #b10f1a; text-align:left;"><b>User:</b></p>
    <p style="color: #b10f1a; text-align:left;"><b>URL:</b></p>
    <p style="color: #b10f1a; text-align:left;"><b>Category:</b> </p>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if i copy and paste this code, all the page has the right background..

Comment: Note that the `bgcolor` attribute has been obsolete for many years.

Comment: Thank you! I guess this issue is with my local host. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You should be used both tags also.

```
    <style>
        html,body{
          background-color:"#DBD7D6";
        } 
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked properly:

```
<html>
 <head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<style>

html {
  min-height: 100%;
}
    h1 {
    font-size:1.7rem;
    font: weight 300;
    color:#b10f1a;
    text-align: center;
  }  

    li {
      float: center;
    }

    li a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover {
      background-color: #111;
    }
    .user {
      color: #b10f1a;
      text-align: left;
    }
    hr {
      color: #b10f1a;
    }
    </style>
</head>

 <body bgcolor="#DBD7D6">


  <h1>Web Page Blocked</h1>

  <p>Access to the web page you were trying to visit has been blocked in accordance with company policy. 
    <br>
    <br>Please contact The Support Desk if you believe this is in error.
    </p>

    <p style="color: #b10f1a; text-align:left;"><b>User:</b></p>
    <p style="color: #b10f1a; text-align:left;"><b>URL:</b></p>
    <p style="color: #b10f1a; text-align:left;"><b>Category:</b> </p>

 </body>
</html>
```

But you should use this instead of bgcolor:

```
<style>
body{
  background-color:"#DBD7D6"
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using BGColor on the body tag in HTML, try adding this to your CSS.

```
body {
    background-color:#f6f6f6; // you can choose any color 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use;

```css
body,html {
    background-color:#DBD7D6;
}
```

This will set the background color of your entire html file
`